# Is it possible to query WMI as Local System?

Tags: windows, wmi, user-accounts, localsystem

Is it possible to query WMI as the Local System account?  I tried to test this out by creating a [Local System instance of Internet Explorer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adioltean/archive/2004/11/27/271063.aspx), and running [WMI Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24045) from it.  I got an error saying that:

> The core WMI components build number could not be determined

This works fine when I run it from my normal user account.  I'm new to WMI, so is there a fundamental reason why this would not be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*creating a Local System instance of Internet Explorer*

I think I am going to have nightmares for weeks.

Anyway, we have code that runs in a service under Local System that queries WMI and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

WMI can be run from any system account, it's not account dependant. You can run WMI queries for other systems accounts from a DOS command prompt for example like the following DOS command (that queries current OS settings):

```
runas /user:"<account_name>" wmic os get /all /format:list
```

**Note:** replace `<account_name>` with the account you want to run command as.

Other tools like `rcmd` or `psexec` can run commands as well worth checking out.

Although WMIC can be executed from command line, utilising WMI does become more complex when utilising it in advanced programming languages.